# Median of Medians algorithm error

Tags: java, algorithm, median-of-medians

I'm implementing a select-kth algorithm using the Median of Medians pivot method.  Specifically, I'm following the [pseudocode listed here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians#Algorithm).  However, my code crashes (error discussed below), I see why it crashes, but I don't understand what I can do about it.

**The Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 32017219
at Selection.partition(Selection.java:173)
```

**The Reason**
In the wiki link, the method `select` will return a *value* if `left == right`.  However, when the mutual recursion is called from the return statement of `pivot`, that means it will return a value (and not an index) back to the parent and the parent will set that value as the `pivotIndex`.

**The Code**

```
public static int alg5(int[] a, int left, int right, int k) {
    if (left == right) {
        return a[left];
    }

    while (true) {
        int pivotIndex = pivot(a, left, right);         
        pivotIndex = partition(a, left, right, pivotIndex);

        if (k == pivotIndex) {
            return a[k];
        } else if (k < pivotIndex) {
            right = pivotIndex - 1;
        } else {
            left = pivotIndex + 1;
        }

    }
}

public static int pivot(int[] a, int left, int right) {
    for (int i = left; i <= right; i = i + 5) {
        int subRight = i + 4;
        if (subRight > right) {
            subRight = right;
        }

        int median5 = partition5(a, i, subRight);
        swap(a, median5, (int)(Math.floor(i / 5)));
    }

    return alg5(a, left, (int)(left + Math.ceil((right - left) / 5) - 1), ((right - left) / 10));
}

public static int partition5(int[] a, int left, int right) {
    Arrays.sort(a);

    return ((a.length - 1) / 2);
}

public static int partition(int[] a, int left, int right, int pivotIndex) {
    int pivotValue = a[pivotIndex];
    a = swap(a, pivotIndex, right);
    int storeIndex = left;

    for (int i = left; i <= right; i++) {
        int aOfi = a[i];
        if (a[i] < pivotValue) {
            swap(a, storeIndex, i);
            storeIndex++;
        }
    }

    swap(a, right, storeIndex);

    return storeIndex;
}
```

I completely understand *why* my code isn't working, I just don't understand how to fix it since it looks to be exactly what the algorithm specifies.  Pointers are greatly appreciated!

Comment: As far as I can tell this is an error in the wiki, try to return `pivotIndex` rather than `a[k]` and compare your result to already implemented k-means algorithms such as in `R` (or perhaps matlab?).

Comment: @ShellFish Same error, out of bounds in Selection.partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few mistakes:

1. The method `pivot` should not modify the array `a`. It should just find a pivot for the future `partition`. A dirty fix is to call `pivot(a.clone(), left, right);`. (You shouldn't do this, just to give you an idea.)
2. `Math.ceil((right - left) / 5)` is an integer division. You should cast them to floats: `Math.ceil(((float)(right - left)) / 5f)`.
3. In `partition5`, you sort the whole array `a`! You should just do comparisons to find the *index* of the median between `a[left]` and `a[right]`.
4. At some point you might have `right < left`, so the first line of `alg5` you should write `if (left >= right)`

Comment: #4 fixed the crash, thank you! I realized #3 through my searching, and have implemented #1 and #2 which changed the output but it is still not the correct answer.  I'm happy that the crash is gone now so I can just focus out why it's giving the wrong answer.  Thank you again for your solution!